# Blender OBJ exporter displays the model facing the wrong way in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, blender

**Edit 3: I now suspect that there's something going on with Blender's OBJ exporter/importer since Maya's export doesn't behave that way - I have updated the title accordingly**

Here's the bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T50424

At the very least, this should help those baffled by this issue as I am.

**Before above edit:**

OBJ files imported using THREE.js' OBJ Importer seem to face the wrong direction.

In Blender: X is forward, Z is up:
[image: Blender showing axis as X forward, Z up]
When exporting, I make sure to keep the Axis consistent, except for the Z/Y flip because of difference in coordinate system in THREE.js:
[image: Blender OBJ exporter settings]

In THREE.js editor, the model gets imported facing Y, and not X, compared to JSON and Collada imports:
[image: THREE.js editor showing incorrect rotation applied]

This leads me to believe, there's something wrong with the OBJ importer.

Models (including Blend file) here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubcxqp9bc4pnr6e/Models.zip?dl=0

Edit: I can confirm that importing the OBJ back into Blender does face the right way, so it's likely not an issue with the OBJ Exporter:
[image: Imported OBJ looks right back in Blender]

Edit 2:**Plot Twist**

Imported both Collada and OBJ into Maya, and it behaves the way THREE.js does.

OBJ is facing Z, and Collada is facing X. I am starting to think this is an issue with Blender's import/export of OBJ files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, blender .obj export can apply a rotation

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_obj.html

> Blender uses Y Forward, Z Up (since the front view looks along the +Y direction)

So your object only gets exported without rotation if you select these settings.

Part of the confusion already starts with "up" and "forward". I think these attempt to point to the blender +Z and +Y direction.

Then "Z up" means that the blender +Z direction ("up") gets mapped to the output +Z direction

And that "Y forward" means that the blender +Y direction ("forward") gets mapped to the output +Y direction.

The X direction then follows from the right handedness.

Note also

- the comboboxes behave buggy, if you select "Up:Z", blender selects "Up:X"!
- not sure why they are using the ambiguous "forward" direction(It can mean  "out of" or "into" the screen), where "to the right" would be much less ambiguous.
- "forward" and "up" suggests that it matters how you rotate the object on the screen before exporting it. I don't think that actually matters